# How to draw the game in a specific portion of a game window

Tags: xna, monogame

[Game Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvsfJ.png)

I am stumped as to how I should go about only drawing the game in the transparent area of the game gui/border. Would I use viewports or something else?

(I have included a sample of the border/gui I plan to use)

Comment: This depends on what kind of game it's going to be, But setting positions to keep it in bounds of the transparent area should be enough. keep in mind, drawing the GUI is part of drawing the game as well. So you shouldn't exclude that entirely.

Comment: It's going to be a touhou-styled shump game. Would restricting the 'game field' to a rectangle be the most efficient way to do this then?

Comment: In case of a bullet hell, I would recommend destroying the projectile objects once they're no longer needed, either through a lifespan, or when it reach out of bounds, You can keep these boundaries within your given rectangle as well.

Comment: If you really want to separate the game render fron the overall render, you should check out render targets [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/xna/bb198676(v%3Dxnagamestudio.30))